# Django How to show user's name in his profile in admin console

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I attached a UserProfile class to User this way:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    home_address = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

I have also implemented auto-creating of UserProfile if needed this way:

```
def user_post_save(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

models.signals.post_save.connect(user_post_save, sender=User)
```

It works fine but I need a small feature - when I go to User Profiles in admin console, I see a list of UserProfiles for existing users. Their titles are shown as **UserProfile object**. I think it would be nice if I could set titles to corresponding user names, for example, **john**, **kenny** etc.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a `__unicode__` method for the UserProfile class:

```
def __unicode__(self):
   return u"Profile for %s" % self.user.get_full_name()
```

Comment: or self.user.username if you prefer